# What's the best way to ask a merchant to accept Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-economy, promotion

When I buy something off the internet, I'd like to ask the merchant to consider accepting Bitcoin. What's the best way to explain to a merchant what Bitcoin is, and what it would do for them? Any success stories?

Comment: Hi NYCBrit, I don't believe that this is a good fit for the Q&A format. "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." I'll let others have their say before closing it though.

Comment: This probably should be moved to the forum, probably under Project Development.

Comment: As a customer, you just don't: it makes no sense and you will be rightly ignored. The only way you can do such a thing is setting up a whole counseling firm aimed to professionally promote Bitcon's use (and helping, for a fee, to set it up).

Comment: I like the question... But anyway, I think that suggesting bit-pay is a good idea because they deal with price fluctuation. Accepting bitcoins without a similar mechanism will probably result in heavy losses for the merchant.

Comment: Hi D.H., sorry you didn't like the question, I'll try to rephrase it as more of a question requiring facts.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should approach the merchant with a group of friends, and each one of you should separately ask him over the span of a couple days a question like: "I would like to buy X from you, but I would like to pay for it in Bitcoins. I understand that this is sort of payment gives you more work, so I am willing to pay Y% more. The current exchange rate at https://mtgox.com is Z USD/BTC and going up, so will you consider selling me X for Q amount of Bitcoins?" If the merchant is small, he probably will be okay with accepting Bitcoins for a moderate transaction, you can even offer waiting a bit until the Bitcoin exchange goes through (or say, a down-payment, so the merchant will know how this thing works before committing to anything). You would probably need to follow up a bit on that inquiry explaining some things about Bitcoins, but not including all the details on how the coins work probably works in your benefit (your email doesn't look like soliciting, but as a more genuine inquiry).

A bigger merchant will probably say no (unless they are tech-savvy), but after a couple people would ask about payment in Bitcoins, the lost opportunity costs would start adding up.

Generally, you can try convincing merchants with some benefits of Bitcoin technology, but probably nothing works better than money incentives and business opportunities.

(note: method not tested)